# When user is inactive for 3 hour the session will expire. php

Tags: php, session

When user is inactive for 3 hour ,How to set  session expire.

Surly this is duplicate question ,

But other threads are not worked for me,

what i have tried upto now is ,

```
<code>
define("APP_SESSION_TIMEOUT","10");
session_cache_expire(APP_SESSION_TIMEOUT);
session_set_cookie_params(APP_SESSION_TIMEOUT*60);
ini_set("session.gc_maxlifetime", APP_SESSION_TIMEOUT * 60);
</code>
```

// Not This code is in my config.php

am not find, success on my above code .. any tips,

i maked any mistake in my code,

---

Hi am not sure, my code is correct,

but still i have a problem ,

am getting confussion,

[click here](http://pastebin.com/m42d1cb3c)

my requirement is when system is active for 3 hours , then login automatically goes to logout,(ie is session expire , when system is in active for 3hr)

But my code , not goign to expire mode,

i have tried somthing like

```
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime',  10800);
```

```
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime',  10800);
```

no luck still.....

---

Am not sure, where is the exact mistake, but finaly,

i fixed the problem last night,

here is the code [click here](http://pastebin.com/m42d1cb3c)

Comment: Please take some time to learn the correct way to use the StackOverflow Markup Syntax. If it is worth our time to answer your question, it is worth your time to learn how to use the site.

Comment: Markdown link: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To inactivate the session exactly after three hours try calling

```
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime',  10800);
```

from your php code.

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
session_set_cookie_params(APP_SESSION_TIMEOUT*60);
```

is probably not what you want. As APP_SESSION_TIMEOUT is defined also as a string, you're multiplying "10" * 60. This will also amount only to 600 seconds (even if PHP does the calculation correctly).

Do this:

```
session_set_cookie_params(3600 * 3); // 3600 seconds (one hour) * 3
session_start();
```

This should set the max. time for the session to three hours.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the php.ini file, you can set it in there. If you don't (which I suspect is the case), you'll need to create a session variable that indicates the start of the session, and continually update that variable with the current timestamp. Then with each access, compare the session variable with the current timestamp and if the difference is greater than 3 hours, call session_destroy().

Comment: This changes affect only when the system is idle ?

Comment: You would have to use timestamps to compare. If you update the timestamp each time the user makes an action, then a difference in session timestamp and post timestamp would be a good measure inactivity. Also, it could be embedded into AJAX calls through context so you could define "idle" as something other than the time between page posts. Keystrokes could even be used if you wanted to go that granular (I wouldn't).